# React native app goes to background when clicked on push notification

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

App is running in foreground.
Then I got push notification.
After I tapped on that push notification, My app status changes foreground to background.
Then It comes to back to foreground.

I use OneSignal dashboard to send a sample push notification.
This happens in Android app.

```
componentDidMount() {
        // One signal notification settings
        OneSignal.configure();
        OneSignal.setLogLevel(5, 0); // adb logcat debug (5) logs
        OneSignal.init('xxxxxxxxxxxx');
        OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(2);
        OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
        OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState((status) => {
            if(status.userId)
                // update userID using props
    });
    }

onIds = (device) => {
    const userId = device.userId;
    if(userId)
       // update userID using props

    OneSignal.removeEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
}
```

I couldn't find out how this happened. I want to stop this app status change when I tap on a push notification. Please tell me some has any idea about this issue.

lib versions,

```
react-native-onesignal: 3.2.11
react-native: 0.57.4
react: 16.6.0-alpha.8af6728
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use "AppState" to specify when to show push notification and after clicking push notification what should be "AppState".

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {AppState, Text} from 'react-native'

class AppStateExample extends Component {

  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!')
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>
    );
  }

}
```

for more info [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only 
answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for ur help @pradnya . Can I keep the app **foreground** after the push notification clicked.

Comment: I have not tried this myself but can you try removing OneSignal.removeEventListener('ids', this.onIds); from onIds() function and add this line in componentWillUnmount() {  OneSignal.removeEventListener('ids', this.onIds);}   Hope this works.

Comment: This solution won't help me because I did the same thing but got the same issue. Did you resolve this issue @JanakaPushpakumara ?